# Clear button click listener in droidparts ClerableEditText

Tags: android-edittext, droidparts

I want to have a click listener for the clear button in the ClerableEditText from droidparts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `ClearableEditText.Listener` instance which `didClearText()` method will be called when the clear button is pressed(or actually released).